# Issue with arithmetic (double = int / int)

Tags: c++

```
int passed(1);
int STUDENTNO(3);

double passRate = (passed / STUDENTNO);
```

The value of `passRate` is shown as `0.00` in the example above when stepping through. How can I make it show correctly as `0.33?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need one or both of the variables on the right hand side to be `double`.

```
double passRate = double(passed) / double(STUDENTNO);
```

Otherwise, as written, the operation will be performed as `int`, then the result will be implicitly converted to `double` before the assignment back to `passRate`. By then it is too late and integer division has already taken place.

Or if your variables were `double` right off the bat, the division would have worked fine.

```
double passed = 1.0;
double STUDENTNO = 3.0;
double passRate = passed / STUDENTNO;
```